# How would you use commas to separate adjectives of equal rights?

Tags: adjectives

I am very confused about these separate adjectives of equal rights.

The example I got was

> The Colt's strong, swift defense enabled them to win.

Comment: The comma shows us that the defense was -separately- strong **and** swift. The two are not connected. But not a strong defense that only applied to swift ones (a strong swift defense).

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344091/do-i-need-to-use-a-comma-between-two-adjectives) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190474/is-it-correct-to-place-comma-between-successive-adjectives)

Comment: 1. What do you mean by *equal rights*?  2. I suspect that either your example misquotes the original or the original is in error. The sentence seems to refer to the Indianapolis Colts (or before them, the Baltimore Colts), an American football team. If so, then the punctuation is wrong and should read instead *The Colts'*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to use a comma between two adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344091/do-i-need-to-use-a-comma-between-two-adjectives) The cumulative / coordinate adjective divide is the field in question. These adjectives can be coordinated ('The Colt's strong and swift defense enabled them to win.') so the comma is appropriate/required if the coordinator is omitted. Contrast 'a dark green car'.

Comment: What are adjectives of equal rights, and what are you confused about?