# comma in "a large, yellow flower"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, commas

"She is a beautiful, smart girl." - she is a beautiful AND smart girl. "This plant produces a large yellow flower." Do I need a comma after large? Or does it make a different connotation? That is, some plants produce large, yellow flowers only, while others produce small, yellow flowers also...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: @Clare: I think this question is about punctuation, not about the order of multiple adjectives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of comma separating two adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54452/use-of-comma-separating-two-adjectives)

Answer (score 0):

*beautiful, smart girl* and *large(,) yellow flower* are not comparable… Please don't ask me why and to me it seems obvious that *beautiful, smart girl* always needs that comma while in *large(,) yellow flower* the comma is always optional.

Very vaguely, is it acceptable to swap *beautiful* and *smart*?

Is it equally acceptable to swap *large* and *yellow*? I suggest that *a yellow large flower* just won't work.

Whether *some plants produce large, yellow flowers only, while others produce small, yellow flowers also* is a wholly different question.

Comment: It's because of order of adjectives. Colors are different from other attributes/adjectives.

Comment: Thanks, Clare. Now that you mention it I don't think *a green long pen/plant/thingy* rings half as true as *a long green…*

Similarly *fat short…* and *short fat…* but either of those is subordinate to colour.

What's going on, please?

Comment: See [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: Oh, wow; thanks. I wish someone had told me that 50 years ago!

Comment: It's not something native speakers ever consciously learn or need to be taught, or are taught. We pick it up naturally.

Comment: Thanks and isn't that telling? Really, vitally, penetrating to the heart of what and how we learn?

Comment: Yellow large flower is trying to distinguish it from white large flower, while large yellow flower is trying to distinguish it from small yellow flower. Now about a comma. Yellow in yellow large flower is modifying 'large flower' but if you say yellow, (comma) large flower, both yellow and large are modifying the flower.

Comment: Really? Please, who says yellow large flower is trying to distinguish it from white large flower, while large yellow flower is trying to distinguish it from small yellow flower?

How would large yellow flower not be distinct from large  white flower? How would either not be distinct from small yellow flower?

What's wrong with Clare's rule for adjective order, please?